# Class with mix of pure virtual and virtual methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

I created an abstract class which has a set of **pure virtual** methods only. There are 3 different classes which have **concrete implementations** of these methods.

Now after writing above structure, I found that some of the methods in the derived classes have identical implementations. So, I moved to the logic to my base class for these functions and made them **virtual** instead of **pure virtual**. Now, the implementations do not need to repeat in the derived classes. This compiles and executes fine.

My base class is a mixture of pure virtual and virtual methods, is it a good design approach to follow a structure like this?

Comment: Why do you think that base classes can only have pure-virtual methods?

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely fine. It is still an abstract base class as long as it contains one or more pure virtual as you are unable to instantiate it, but moving common functionality there is a good thing.

Comment: If you really wanted to keep your root interface completely pure (ex: hiding implementation entirely within a dynamic factory lib) you could also just implement an intermediate BaseImpl that inherits from your pure-virtual interface, implements the common code, reaffirms the remaining pure virtuals, and your concrete finals can inherit from *that*.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius as I said it is compiling & working. My question is related to design principles. basically is it a good design approach ?

Comment: @SegmentationFault And my question was related to the same. Let me clarify: why do you think it's a bad design?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I did not necessarily think that it was bad. but I was unsure whether it was good or bad design. so wanted to confirm this with the experts. pls add your thoughts if you have any (adv/dis-adv)

Comment: @SegmentationFault Well, I, personally don't see any disadvantages, since _any_ pattern that eliminates code copying, is better. Code copying, in general, should be avoided, and it _is_ smell of a bad design. And that's why I didn't write an answer of my own, since it would've been too short, for my liking :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius agree to your point

Answer (score 5):

It's absolutely fine, although a pattern does seem to have emerged where you would put *all* and *only* your pure virtual functions in a class to be regarded as more of an *interface*.

You would then define a class that *implements* the "common" parts of that interface, and have your 3 classes inherit from that class.

Over time, it seems that this lends itself to code that is more scalable and easier to maintain.

Java, out of interest, pretty much forces the use of this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationships between the classes, obviously.   In other words, it is a design or implementation choice (i.e. up to you, as long as you can justify it sensibly).  Technically, there is nothing preventing a class from having a mix of virtual, pure virtual, non-virtual, and static member functions.

If two derived classes override an inherited virtual function and implement it in the same way, then - yes - I would seriously consider providing that function into the base class.   However, there are more questions I would ask - such as whether it makes sense for ALL derived classes to default to that implementation of the function.   From a code reuse perspective, such a thing might make sense.   From a design perspective, it may not.

That said, if it makes sense to treat a particular implementation of a function as a "default" (i.e. all derived classes default to using that, unless they override that function) then there is no harm in placing that definition in a base class.

As a crude example where what you suggest wouldn't make sense, consider this

```
  class Aircraft
  {
       public:
            virtual void Manoeuvre() = 0;
  };

  class Hornet : public Aircraft   //  F/A-18 hornet fighter aircraft
  {
        public:

              void Manoeuvre();
  };

  class Tomcat : public Aircraft    //  F-14 tomcat fighter aircraft
  {
        public:

               void Manoeuvre();
  };
```

Let's say that, because of the fidelity of our modelling, that both derived classes had the same `Manoeuvre()` functions - they are both supersonic fighter aircraft (so will probably employ similar style of manoeuvre, albeit with different parameterisation).   However, that is not sufficient to move their `Manoeuvre()` function to the base class, because there are aircraft that are not supersonic fighters, such as

```
  class Hercules : public Aircraft    //  C-130 hercules cargo plan
  {
        public:

               void Manoeuvre();
  };
```

In this case, it does not make sense for a `Hercules` to inherit manoeuvring capability of a supersonic fighter, or vice versa.   So it doesn't make sense for this to be supplied by the `Aircraft` class.

In this case, I might consider introducing intermediate classes, such as `Fighter` (which could be a common base of `Hornet` and `Tomcat`, but not `Hercules`) and - if I sought to represent multiple types of cargo aircraft - possibly a `CargoPlane` to be a common base for those.   Then both `Fighter` and `CargoPlane` might derive from `Aircraft`, but `Aircraft` does not supply functionality that only makes sense to some aircraft types.

Incidental comment:  although some people claim otherwise, there is nothing in C++ preventing a pure virtual function from having a definition (implementation).   The meaning is that the function MUST be overridden by derived classes, but there is a default definition (which can be explicitly called by functions in derived classes) provided by the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is fine. However: If these are all the classes you have, there's no need to make the base class implementations `virtual`.

Comment: ITYM, if these are all the derived class you will ever have. ;-)

Comment: Yes and no. If these classes are part of a public API, or might require binary backwards compatibility, design with the future in mind (`virtual`). Otherwise you might make the methods virtual later if requirements change...